# Sort by enum field with hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a ENUM field in my entity

```
@Field(store=Store.NO,index=Index.YES,analyze=Analyze.NO)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@FieldBridge(impl = EnumBridge.class)
@SortableField
private Status status;
```

and i want to sort entities by this field. So i've create a *Sort* in Hibernate search:

```
Sort sort = qb
        .sort()
        .byDistance()
        .onField("location.location")
        .fromLatitude(sfq.getTheCenterLatitude())
        .andLongitude(sfq.getTheCenterLongitude())
        .andByField("status")
        .createSort();
```

(i also sort by distance, but it doesn't matter)

BUT, when i try to search i see this error

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /api/search/: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'status' (expected=SORTED). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'status' (expected=SORTED). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.
```

How to sort by enum field in hibernate search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting `<property name="hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy" value="none"/>` in property.xml. I don't know how, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to reindex after you added `@SortableField`?